# altering permissions on docker-created named volumes

Tags: docker, file-permissions, docker-volume

I'm attempting to use a docker volume to share data between two containers— where one container will write some data to the volume, and the other will read it.

One of the constraints is that I will need to automate the process using docker-compose— so solutions where a user changes permissions from inside the container will not work

how do i loosen the permissions for a shared volume managed by docker so that a process can write to it?

**for additional context:**
the data being written will be written by postgres, and will be read by a nest js app

Comment: That sounds like you don't need a shared volume at all; instead, you'd use an SQL client library to make a connection to the database container.  (Using a network protocol of some sort to avoid the shared volume is probably better practice, if I've misunderstood the setup.)

Comment: In addition to using the network to connect microservices (which is the right answer), if you need to control permissions on volumes, it's not clear why you can't do that in the container image. The compose file specifies the image to use, so specify one with the volume features you need.

Comment: @DavidMaze— we're exporting some large tables into csv— which must write to the machine that the db is running on— the only other way to do that is pg_dump, which still writes to the machine the db is writing on (the latter im less sure of)

Comment: @BMitch my understanding is that using a named volume in compose (one that is shared) must be defined outside the container image— how else do you define a volume that two different containers can reference? (particularly a volume managed by docker, and not predefined on the host machine?)

Answer (score 0):

For now, my chosen workaround:

```
shared_volume_setup:
    image: alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_exports:/tmp/exports
    entrypoint: [ "sh", "-c", "sleep 10 && chmod 777 /tmp/exports"]
```

which spins up a different container with the sole purpose of altering the docker-managed volume

I'm still seeking a better answer (using compose config on the volume rather than a separate workload container) but this works fine for now